# @ManyToMany with EclipseLink 2.5.2 and Jackson 2.4.4

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jackson, eclipselink

While trying to update an entity, I fire a REST request: `PUT <ip>/categories/5` with a JSON body: `{"id":"4","name":"otherCategory","contentList":[]}`

error message is:

```
WARN  [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter] 
(default task-27) Failed to evaluate deserialization for type [simple type, class 
com.example.domain.assetmanagement.Category]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Can not handle managed/back reference 'users-roles': no back reference property 
found from type [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, 
class com.example.domain.user.permission.Role]]
```

Category.java does not contain this relation, it only has three properties id, name, and contentList

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID_CATEGORY")
private String id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
@JsonManagedReference("category-content")
private List<Content> contentList;

[+getters/setters]
```

The relation is defined in User and in Role, as described in: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/ManyToMany

User.java:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(
                        name = "user_id",
                        referencedColumnName = "id"
                )
        },
        inverseJoinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id",
                referencedColumnName = "id"
        )
)
@JsonManagedReference("users-roles")
private List<Role> roles;
```

Role.java:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private List<User> users;
```

When I add @JsonBackReference to the users property in Role.java, I get the following error:

```
WARN  [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter] 
(default task-28) Failed to evaluate deserialization for type [simple type, class
com.example.domain.assetmanagement.Category]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Can not handle managed/back reference 'users-roles': back reference type 
(java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.example.domain.user.User)
```

Comment: Could you have an older version of the classes on your classpath with test mappings that are no longer valid?  I don't see how it would associate a users-roles reference to the category class otherwise.

Comment: Category has never contained this association. I thought it went through contentList and other entities in the relation scheme until it arrives at users-roles.

Comment: For now I have added @JsonIgnore to both sides of the relation to make it work. I fetch the users/roles separately.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/deserializing-objects-with-bi-directional-many-to-many-relations you need to use @JsonIdentityInfo on both entities instead of the @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference on the mappings.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not fit to the posted question. Relating to the manual I do not need the `@JsonBackReference` in this case (ManyToMany), and I already tested it (see end of question for details, this was not added afterwards).

Comment: The bottom of the article mentions the JsonIdentityInfo annotation, which is what you really should be using as JsonBackReference is not supported on collections according to http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/how-to-handle-cyclic-references-in-a-bidirectional-many-to-many